# Snippet title problem after upgrade from wagtail 1.13 to 2.0

Tags: wagtail

I am working on wagtail upgrade on a site from version 1.13.4 . Was mostly following this post https://wagtail.org/blog/upgrading-wagtail/ . However, since the first update to wagtail 2.0 snippet titles are wrong. I could sort it out on the templated front end pages, but they still appear wrong on the admin panel.

[How titles are displayed on the admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnOwD.png)
[And this same issue is with fields that link to those snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cjqZ.png)

I got as far as updating wagtail to 2.4, since the blog post said that it should support python 3.7, but issue still persists. As far as I can tell, there are no error messages on the terminal output, migrations run without any issues. Any clue where I should start looking?

This should be the relevant artist snippet declaration from the project

```
@register_snippet
class Artist(index.Indexed, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

    objects = ArtistQuerySet.as_manager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    name_encoded = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=512)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    @property
    def status(self):
        # If there are no events currently attached to this artist
        if not self.artistatevent_set.all():
            return NO_CURRENT_DATES

        # This artist does have some events, next see if there's any tickets
        if self.total_ticket_count is not 0:

            # Are they all the same type?
            if self.available_ticket_count == self.total_ticket_count:
                return AVAILABLE
            if self.sold_out_ticket_count == self.total_ticket_count:
                return SOLD_OUT
            if self.cancelled_ticket_count == self.total_ticket_count:
                return CANCELLED
            if self.unavailable_ticket_count == self.total_ticket_count:
                return UNAVAILABLE

        # See if we have ANY of the following
        if self.available_ticket_count:
            return AVAILABLE
        if self.coming_soon_ticket_count:
            return COMING_SOON
        if self.sold_out_ticket_count:
            return SOLD_OUT

        # Nothing matched, so default
        return UNAVAILABLE

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
    ]

    search_fields = [
        index.SearchField('name', partial_match=True),
    ]
```

EDIT:

This is a snippet from admin.py declaration

```
...
class NameIDAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'id')
...
admin.site.register(Artist, NameIDAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When upgrading from Python 2 to 3, you should replace the `__unicode__` method with `__str__`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods